# How to manage AggregateException is throwing while PostAsync call?

Tags: c#, timeout, dotnet-httpclient

I am getting AggregateException while client.PostAsyc call even I have set long timeout.

Here is my code.

```
try
{
    StoresList objlist = new StoresList();
    Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
    Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer session = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings;

    var contents = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[] 
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("userapi", session.Values["userapi"].ToString()),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("keyapi", session.Values["keyapi"].ToString()),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("notification_flag","1"),                 
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("token", localSettings.Values["deviceid"].ToString()),
        });

    using (var client = new HttpClient()  { Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(4) } )
    {
        var result = client.PostAsync(session.Values["URL"] + "/abcd/", contents).Result;

        if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string data = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            if (data.Contains("activate") || data.Contains("enable"))
            {
                //Please activate the Mobile Assistant Extension 
                return null;
            }

            if (data != null)
            {
                List<Stores> objStores = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LoginResponse>(data).stores;

                foreach (var item in objStores)
                {
                    Stores objs = new Stores();
                    {
                        objs.id = item.id;
                        objs.name = item.name;
                        objlist.Add(objs);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
    return objlist;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
    return null;
}
```

Can anybody suggest how to manage this? Sometime I get AggregateException.

I have referred following link but I still get error. Event I have set timeout.

[How can I tell when HttpClient has timed out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10547895/how-can-i-tell-when-httpclient-has-timed-out)

[AggregateException is throwing while waiting for PostAsJsonAsync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20417383/aggregateexception-is-throwing-while-waiting-for-postasjsonasync)

[Whats the difference between HttpClient.Timeout and using the WebRequestHandler timeout properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26313172/whats-the-difference-between-httpclient-timeout-and-using-the-webrequesthandler)

Answer (score 4):

Add `async` to your method definition and use `await` instead of `.Result`.

Using `.Result` blocks the thread and you lose all the benfits of using the Async methods.

Using `await` "unwraps" not only the data, but the exceptions too (so you will get an actual exception rather than AggregateException).

```
var result = await client.PostAsync(session.Values["URL"] + "/abcd/", contents);

...

string data = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

It's a bit long, but here is a good video about using async/await: https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/aspConf/aspConf/Async-in-ASP-NET

It's worth the watch.

Answer (score 0):

AggregateException is a collection of all exceptions encountered while doing an async task.

If you just want to check what the exception encountered was without doing any handling, you can do something like:

```
catch (AggregateException ae)
{
    // This will just throw the first exception, which might not explain everything/show the entire trace.
    throw ae.InnerException
}
```

or

```
catch (AggregateException ae)
{
    // This will flatten the entire exception stack to a string.
    throw new Exception(ae.ToString())
}
```